# Why code in not covered for verify in mokito?

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito, junit-jupiter

This is the service file which has save method. This method is not covering in code coverage. These repository's noting but just a jpa repository's

```java
@Service
public class ProcessFileService {

    @Autowired
    private ProcessFileRepository processFileRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProcessRunRepository processRunRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void save(ProcessRun processRun, List<ProcessFile> processFiles) {

        processRunRepository.save(processRun);
        for (ProcessFile processFile : processFiles) {
            processFile.setProcessRun(processRun);
            processFileRepository.save(processFile);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the Test class and its done by verify()

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ProcessFileServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private ProcessFileRepository processFileRepository;
    @Mock
    private ProcessRunRepository processRunRepository;

    @Test
    void ProcessSave() {
        ProcessRun processRun = new ProcessRun();
        processRun.setEndDateTime("30/08/2022");
        processRun.setNumFilesFailed(1L);
        processRun.setNumFilesProcessed(1L);
        processRun.setNumFilesTransferred(1L);
        processRun.setStartDateTime("30/08/2022");

        ProcessFile processFile = new ProcessFile();
        processFile.setCurrentRetryAttempt(1);
        processFile.setFileName("file.txt");
        processFile.setSuccessfulYN(true);
        processFile.setTransferDateTime("30/08/2022");

        List<ProcessFile> processFiles = new ArrayList<ProcessFile>();
        processFiles.add(processFile);

        ProcessFileService processFileService = mock(ProcessFileService.class);

        doNothing().when(processFileService).save(processRun,  processFiles);
        processFileService.save(processRun,  processFiles);


        verify(processFileService, times(1)).save(processRun, processFiles);
    }

}
```

Please help me here what is i am missing here, i am new to junit.

Answer (score 0):

You mocked your object under test, and in addition, stubbed method under test to do nothing (which by the way is the default behaviour for mocks).

You need to construct a proper instance of class under test, not mock it.
With MockitoExtension, a simple way to do this is:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ProcessFileServiceTest {
    
    @Mock
    private ProcessFileRepository processFileRepository;
    @Mock
    private ProcessRunRepository processRunRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    ProcessFileService processFileService

    ...
}
```

Comment: When i changed it like this it shows,org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!

Comment: do not call `when` and `verify` on method under test - you want to call the method under test, not stub it